# How can i open a new webpage after i click a checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I open a new web page after I click a `checkbox` using `c# asp net MVC` ?

I need open the new view `Index_p` when selected checkbox `Breakfast` in the view `Index`

My view `Index`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="background-color: darkorange; border:3px solid; font-weight:bold;">
            <h5 style="font-weight: bold;"> Breakfast: @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Breakfast, true) </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My model:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public bool Breakfast { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PersonModel person)
{
    bool ischecked = person.Breakfast;

    if(ischecked == true)
        return RedirectToAction("Index_p");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(person);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the updated code, RedirectToAction only when you are trying to redirect to action method not view.

```
if(ischecked == true)
    return View("Index_p");

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(person);
}
```